# Zeros at the end of DateTime

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

How to delete zeros after datetime via EntityFramework?
when i add record to database it displays it with zeros at the end in my datebase
[image]

I specified DisplayFormat but when adding migration my Up method is empty

```
 [Column("Birth date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{yyyy/MM/dd}")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you don't want a time portion, don't use a `datetime2(7)`, use a `date`. `date` (as its name suggests) just contains a date value.

Comment: DisplayFormat is for displaying the value on a page, where it's converted to a string. The database is unaware of that attribute

Comment: In a fit of "about time" modern versions of .NET also introduced the [DateOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly) and [TimeOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly) types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
[Column(TypeName="Date")]
[Column("Birth date")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Please read more here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt